# sql assignment, concatinating while creating a table

Tags: sql

Sorry about fist post, hope this made it more eye friendly

Stuck on an assignment and at a complete loss for how to do this. 
I am supposed to make these 4 into a table, but how do I do the bit with concatenating the table?

--Package(Table name)

--package_code(Column name)

--destination(Column name)

--price(Column name)

--passport_required(Column name)

package_code is the primary key

*package_code stores a 6-character code that you create by concatenating a 3-letter airport code with an arbitrary 3-digit number*(This is the part that has me baffled,)

Example:  YKF001

YKF is the airport code for Kitchener-Waterloo Regional Airport

001 identifies a particular travel package (package 1 zero filled on the left)

Comment: please use code formatting to set up things like table definitions.  It's much nicer than us staring at a paragraph.

Comment: post required schema with proper format

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL there is a function, `GROUP_CONCAT()`, which allows you to concatenate the values from multiple rows. Example:

```
SELECT 1 AS a, GROUP_CONCAT(code ORDER BY code ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS my_code
FROM users 
WHERE <some condition>
GROUP BY a
```